# The method 'mapIndexed' isn't defined for the type 'List'

Tags: flutter

I just copied some lines from one file to another and came along the above error message. Since data types in the new files were alike, it was strange to get the error.

See the reason below

Answer (score 0):

I had no further detail or rectifying action suggested for this error.

However, the solution was a simple

`import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

Strange why IntelliJ Idea did not suggest to import the missing package. So, just in case someone else struggles with this.

Comment: Have you added package `collection` to your pubspec?